# EthTx adapter won't respond in Chainlink job, fails with "transaction reverted on-chain"

Tags: oracles, chainlink

We're using the standard truffle box (https://github.com/smartcontractkit/box) to deploy Chainlink contract ($LINK definition, Oracle, sample end-user contract, etc) on a private Ethereum testnet.

Everything works, as in I can trigger jobs from smart contract calls on-chain, unless my job spec has ends with "EthTx" adapter. If I end my job with an "EthTx" adapter, the task will fail with the only error being "transaction reverted on-chain".

My Oracle ETH accounts are well-funded, so lack of gas for running the transactions isn't an issue. Also, all the other adapters work without failing...so it's not a problem with the HTTP endpoint being down, path being wrong, or casting the wrong types. What's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things that can be happening, but *most likely* it is due to the fact that your oracle contract doesn't have its fulfillment permissions set correctly.

When you deploy the oracle contract, you also have to call the `setfulfillmentpermission` to `true` for you node. You can do this in remix/etherscan, or [via a script](https://gist.github.com/PatrickAlphaC/6a2f26e86ecc3ec8f8aaa230ff63199d). In this script, you'll need a:

1. `PRIVATE_KEY`environment variable connected to the same wallet that deploy the oracle contract
2. `KOVAN_RPC_URL` environment variable connected the blockchain of choice.
3. You'll need to set `oracleAddress` to the oracle contract address.
4. You'll need to set `address` to the address of your Chainlink node.

Hope it helps.