# EthTx adapter in Chainlink job, fails with “transaction reverted on-chain”

Tags: solidity, remix, chainlink

I have gone through the existing error link [EthTx Adapter in Chainlink Job](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/95019/ethtx-adapter-wont-respond-in-chainlink-job-fails-with-transaction-reverted-o)

and the solutions recommended is also tried, but still i am facing the same issue. Approach I taken to debug is given below

```
Network: Apothem ( Xinfin )
Eth_URL: wss://ws.apothem.network
Chain_id: 51
```

- Deployed the Oracle contrct in Apothem network using https://remix.xinfin.network/
- Deployed the testClient contract with Oracle Address & Link Contract overriden in Constructor in Apothem Network using remix
- Deployed the Oracle contrct in Apothem network using https://remix.xinfin.network/
- Ensured, setfullfilmentPermission method is done by overriding chainlink node address(regular) , with true flag
- Funded my testclient contract with LINK token
- Created the job in Chainlink node UI using following job spec

```
{
  "initiators": [
    {
      "type": "external",
      "params": {
        "name": "xdc",
        "body": {
          "endpoint": "xinfin-testnet",
          "addresses": [ Oracle contract address]
        }
      }
    }
  ],
    "tasks": [
    {
      "type": "cryptoprice",
    },
    {
      "type": "Copy"
    },
    {
      "type": "Multiply"
    },
    { "type": "EthUint256" },
    { "type": "EthTx" }
  ]
}
```

Have ensured the external adapter is running in port i.e, 5000 and bridge has been created in chainlink node ui. When I trigger the createRequest method by overriding jobid, coin and market. Job is triggering in Chainlink node and I could see that all tasks are completed except EthTx adapter which throws, "Transaction reverted txn On chain" error

```
contract RequestClient is ChainlinkClient, Ownable {
    address private oracle;
    bytes32 private jobId;
    uint256 constant private ORACLE_PAYMENT = 2 * LINK;
    
    uint256 public volume;

    constructor(address _link) public {
        setChainlinkToken(_link);
        oracle = 0xcee7a06ca7002f778e70f8f14a28534986c1aa28;
    }
    event requestCreated(address indexed requester,bytes32 indexed jobId, bytes32 indexed requestId);
    
    event requestFulfilled(bytes32 indexed _requestId, uint256 _data);

  
    /*
     * Create a request and send it to default Oracle contract
    */
      function createRequest(
        string _jobId,
        string _coin,
        string _market
      )
        public
        onlyOwner
        returns (bytes32 requestId)
      {
        // create request instance
        Chainlink.Request memory req = buildChainlinkRequest(stringToBytes32(_jobId), address(this), this.fulfill.selector);
        req.add("endpoint", "price");
        req.add("fsym", _coin);
        req.add("tsyms", _market);
        req.add("copyPath", _market);
        req.addInt("times", 100);
        // send request & payment to Chainlink oracle
        requestId = sendChainlinkRequestTo(oracle, req, ORACLE_PAYMENT);
        emit requestCreated(msg.sender, stringToBytes32(_jobId), requestId);
    }
    
    /**
     * Receive the response in the form of uint256
     */ 
    function fulfill(bytes32 _requestId, uint256 _volume) public recordChainlinkFulfillment(_requestId)
    {
        emit requestFulfilled(_requestId, volume);
        volume = _volume;
    }
    
    function stringToBytes32(string memory source)
        private
        pure
        returns (bytes32 result)
    {
        bytes memory tempEmptyStringTest = bytes(source);

        if (tempEmptyStringTest.length == 0) {
            return 0x0;
        }

        assembly {
            result := mload(add(source, 32))
        }
    }
}
```

Please note, I tried to debug the revertreason from txhash, but i dont see any revertreason parms available in txHash receipt.

Any direction, help would be really greatfull.

Comment: Where is your fulfill method? If you have one can you post it? I need to see that to be able to debug this properly.

Comment: Added the fulfil method above, please check & thanks for the reply.

Comment: What are your ETH_CHAIN_ID env variables and ETH_URL set to?
Reference: 
https://docs.chain.link/docs/configuration-variables/

Comment: Also make sure you are not just setting "SetFullffillmentPermission" to only true but in the format "node_addreess, true" as seen in this tutorial:
https://docs.chain.link/docs/fulfilling-requests/#add-your-node-to-the-oracle-contract

Comment: Hi - thanks for the reply -- please see below ..ETH_CHAIN_ID=51, ETH_URL=wss://ws.apothem.network and yes, I have passed both node_address and true in setfulfillmentpermission method.

Comment: Hi @ZakAyesh - Any other recommendations?. I am stuck with this issue for a week now and no clue yet.

Comment: I got the response finally. and yes, the external-initiators plays a major role here.!.. ANyone need help, let me know.