# EthTx Adapter in Chainlink - Txn Construct Details

Tags: solidity, chainlink

I am setting up chainlink node for Xinfin Network for Apothem. While submitting the transactions, it is reverted on chain. We tried to debug and the json looks like below.

```
{
      "id": "9a750361-9f69-40dd-8531-11d164d0ce69",
      "result": {
        "data": {
          "data": "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",
          "result": "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008be",
          "topics": [
            "0xd8d7ecc4800d25fa53ce0372f13a416d98907a7ef3d8d3bdd79cf4fe75529c65",
            "0x3078363636323339333733393336333736343636333533313632333433333335"
          ],
          "address": "0xe86e772417d3f1fc9a0a6f0dc25c04ac2c60759d",
          "logIndex": "0x3",
          "blockHash": "0x56a0ae954a3c1ae8321dd7d02f86ba75e6d2bddef60de746ed0b6f9acff69b85",
          "blockNumber": "0x12f1de6",
          "transactionHash": "0x94c895e831bf10787a5f7ea33b6e476098b2316890edf983f0c8f9d3d1f0b504",
          "transactionIndex": "0x0"
        },
        "error": "transaction 0xcb2b9135a3952403611f00206a82a2745e6c5b7f90331503088afdc4edbe3eea reverted on-chain"
      },
      "status": "errored",
      "task": {
        "ID": 202,
        "jobSpecId": "fb97967df51b4357bfb4b4dc8de68c9d",
        "type": "ethtx",
        "confirmations": null,
        "params": {
        },
        "CreatedAt": "2021-06-19T14:53:23.259696+05:30",
        "UpdatedAt": "2021-06-19T14:53:23.259696+05:30",
        "DeletedAt": null
      },
      "minimumConfirmations": null,
      "confirmations": null
    }
```

When I tried to debug the "Data" value using decoder, it is like below

```
{ method: null,
  types: [ 'address' ],
  inputs: [ '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000' ],
  names: [ '_link' ] }
```

Please assist, is this the reason txn is failing?,what is the expected construct. I do not find details regarding these in chainlink.

My job spec is

````
{
  "initiators": [
    {
      "type": "external",
      "params": {
        "name": "xdc",
        "body": {
          "endpoint": "xinfin-testnet",
          "addresses": ["0xe86e772417d3f1fc9a0a6f0dc25c04ac2c60759d"]
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "tasks": [
    {
      "type": "cryptoprice"
    },
    {
      "type": "copy",
        "params": {
        "copyPath": [
          "result"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "multiply"
    },
    {
      "type": "ethuint256"
    },
    {
       "type": "EthTx"
    }
  ]
}```
````

Comment: can you also post the on-chain code that's consuming this job? In particular, the function that does the request, and the function that fulfills the response

Comment: Hi - thanks for the reply, this issue link has the details -> https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/101816/ethtx-adapter-in-chainlink-job-fails-with-transaction-reverted-on-chain?noredirect=1#comment125172_101816

Comment: Our blockchain is Xinfin Network, and I am bit curious to know -- Can ETHTx adapter handle the parameters? or should we customize our external adapter to handle it?,

Comment: yes if you're just sending the price of a crypto (ETH in this case by the looks of it), then it should handle it fine. Anyway, according to the blockchain explorer, the tx was successful? https://explorer.apothem.network/tx/0xcb2b9135a3952403611f00206a82a2745e6c5b7f90331503088afdc4edbe3eea#overview 
Can you confirm the CL node has enough ETH to fulfill the request?

Comment: yes you are right, but it is not succssful transaction. We have "No block confirmation" shown in explorer and this txn is not included in blocks.  Yes I have enough XDC and contract is funded.

Comment: I got the response finally. and yes, the external-initiators plays a major role here.!.. ANyone need help, let me know.

Comment: @Lokesh, glad to hear you figured it out! Could you add how you solved it below so others who have the same issue can solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it by following below steps: Mostly the tranaction revert occurs due to few factors, such as "fulfilmentissue" or "enough fund not available" issue. but in my case, it was missing - "Dataprefix & functionselector" values.

So I have setup a external-initiators and created a blockchain file for Xinfin, made sure it works fine which resulted proper value in Txn construct.

When you are setting up Chainlink for your own blockchain, make sure you are creating your own blockchain file.

I will share the document on how to do the same, when ready.

thanks